# Is it possible to import vb.net form to blend?

Tags: winforms

I have created a windows form using visual studio design, that is simply drag n drop component into the form from Toolbox.
Is it possible to import it into Blend and change its appearence using Blend?

I opened the project from Blend but ony the code appears not the form itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - winforms applications are not WPF applications.

Blends knows XAML, the markup language of WPF applications - it has no understanding of winforms.

If you want to work with both Blend and Visual Studio in one project, use WPF.

Comment: The transition from win forms to WPF is it easy or I have to rewrite my code from scratch?

Comment: @Novemberland - You can use a very similar style, but then you are not doing WPF "properly". To do it "properly" takes time, but for a simple application you can "do winforms in WPF".